# Thoughts on improving these queries (MySQL) ? My production machine is seeing 10 sec times on them (using a sample size of over 1000)

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

Table definition and queries explained:

item |

```
CREATE TABLE `item` ( 
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`item_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`site_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`title` varchar(175) NOT NULL, 
`desc` text NOT NULL, 
`url` varchar(767) NOT NULL, 
`price` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`photo_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`photo_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
`has_photo` enum('yes','no','pending') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending', 
`added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`normalized_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`location` varchar(128) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`), 
KEY `item_type_id` (`item_type_id`), 
KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`), 
KEY `site_id` (`site_id`), 
KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`), 
KEY `created_at` (`created_at`), 
KEY `added_at` (`added_at`), 
KEY `normalized_time` (`normalized_time`), 
KEY `typephototime` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`), 
KEY `brandidphoto` (`brand_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), 
KEY `brandidphoto2` (`brand_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), 
KEY `idphoto` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), 
KEY `idphototime` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`), 
KEY `idphoto2` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), 
KEY `typepricebrandid` (`item_type_id`,`price`,`brand_id`,`item_id`), 
KEY `sellertypephototime` (`seller_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`), 
KEY `typephoto` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=508885 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

mysql> explain SELECT item.* FROM `item` WHERE item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" ORDER BY normalized_time DESC LIMIT 1;

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | item | ref | item_type_id,typephototime,idphoto,idphototime,idphoto2,typepricebrandid,typephoto | typephototime | 5 | const,const | 69528 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE item_type_id = "1" AND (price BETWEEN "25" AND "275") AND brand_id = "10" ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1;

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | item | index | item_type_id,brand_id,typephototime,brandidphoto,brandidphoto2,idphoto,idphototime,idphoto2,typepricebrandid,typephoto | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 203 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

mysql> explain SELECT item.* FROM `item` WHERE item.brand_id = "10" AND item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" ORDER BY normalized_time DESC LIMIT 1;

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | item | index | item_type_id,brand_id,typephototime,brandidphoto,brandidphoto2,idphoto,idphototime,idphoto2,typepricebrandid,typephoto | normalized_time | 8 | NULL | 502397 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (2.15 sec)
```

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `item` WHERE item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" ;

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | item | ref | item_type_id,typephototime,idphoto,idphototime,idphoto2,typepricebrandid,typephoto | typephoto | 5 | const,const | 71135 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Why so many keys? Many of them look redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following indexes are redundant because they match the left columns of another index.  You can almost certainly drop these indexes and save some space and overhead.

```
KEY `item_type_id` (`item_type_id`), /* redundant */
KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`), /* redundant */
KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`), /* redundant */
KEY `idphototime` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`),  /* redundant */
KEY `brandidphoto2` (`brand_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), /* redundant */
KEY `idphoto` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), /* redundant  */
KEY `idphoto2` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), /* redundant */
KEY `typephoto` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`) /* redundant */
```

That leaves the following indexes:

```
KEY `site_id` (`site_id`), 
KEY `created_at` (`created_at`), 
KEY `added_at` (`added_at`), 
KEY `normalized_time` (`normalized_time`), 
KEY `brandidphoto` (`brand_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`), 
KEY `typephototime` (`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`),
KEY `typepricebrandid` (`item_type_id`,`price`,`brand_id`,`item_id`), 
KEY `sellertypephototime` (`seller_id`,`item_type_id`,`has_photo`,`normalized_time`),
```

You can also use a tool like [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) to find redundant indexes.

Next consider the storage engine:

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=508885 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Almost always, InnoDB is a better choice than MyISAM.  Not only for performance, but for data integrity and crash safety.  InnoDB has been the default storage engine since 2010, and it's the only storage engine that is actively getting improved.  I'd recommend making a copy of this table, changing the storage engine to InnoDB, and compare its performance with respect to your queries.

Next let's consider indexes for the queries:

```
SELECT item.* FROM `item` WHERE item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" 
ORDER BY normalized_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I would choose an index on `(item_type_id, has_photo, normalized_time)` and that's the index it's currently using, which is `typephototime`.

One way to optimize this further would be to fetch only the columns in the index.  That's when you see "Using index" in the EXPLAIN plan, it can be a huge improvement for performance.

Another important factor is to make sure that your index is cached in memory: increase `key_buffer_size` if you use MyISAM or `innodb_buffer_pool_size` if you use InnoDB to be as large as all the indexes you want to remain in memory.  Because you don't want to run a query that needs to scan an index larger than your buffers; it causes a lot of swapping.

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE item_type_id = "1" AND (price BETWEEN "25" AND "275") AND brand_id = "10" 
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I would choose an index on `(item_type_id, brand_id, price)`, but this query is currently using the PRIMARY index.  You should create a new index.

```
SELECT item.* FROM `item` WHERE item.brand_id = "10" AND item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" 
ORDER BY normalized_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I would choose an index on `(item_type_id, brand_id, has_photo, normalized_time)`.  You should create a new index.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `item` WHERE item.item_type_id = "1" AND item.has_photo = "yes" ;
```

I would choose an index on `(item_type_id, has_photo)` and that's the index it's currently using, which is `typephoto`.  It's also getting the "Using index" optimization, so the only other improvement could be to make sure there's enough buffer to hold the index in memory.

It's hard to optimize `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries because they naturally have to scan a lot of rows.

The other strategy to optimize COUNT(*) is to calculate the counts offline, and store them either in a summary table or in an in-memory cache like memcached so you don't have to recalculate them every time someone loads a page.  But that means you have to update the counts every time someone adds or deletes a row in the `item` table, which could be *more* costly depending on how frequently that happens.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would suggest changing:

- You don't need all those indexes. You really only need indexes on fields that are accessed a lot, like foreign key fields. Remove all the indexes except ones on ID fields.
- You should be storing dates as nulls unless there is actual data.
- Stay away from the enum data type, use smallint with flags representing each value. Example, 0 pending, 1 yes, 2 no.

Alongside reducing the size of the database, it makes things much cleaner. Your new table structure would look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` ( 
    `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `item_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `title` varchar(175) NOT NULL, 
    `desc` text NOT NULL, 
    `url` varchar(767) NOT NULL, 
    `price` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `photo_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `photo_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    `has_photo` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `added_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `updated_at` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    `created_at` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    `normalized_time` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    `location` varchar(128) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`), 
    KEY `item_type_id` (`item_type_id`), 
    KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`), 
    KEY `site_id` (`site_id`), 
    KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=508885 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would also suggest using `utf8_unicode_ci` as the collate, `utf8` as the charset, and `InnoDB` as the engine.

But first off, remove all those keys and try again. Also remove the aliasing on the 3rd query.

`SELECT * FROM item WHERE brand_id = "10" AND item_type_id = "1" AND has_photo = "yes" ORDER BY normalized_time DESC LIMIT 1;`